# Missing table socialaccount_socialapp_sites, how do I fix this?

Tags: django, django-allauth

Whenever I try to add a social app, I get an error that the table socialaccount_socialapp_sites is missing. I had some set up problems because I forgot to include django.contrib.sites at first, but after fixing that I seem to get everything to work up until adding a socialapp.

I have already run migrate and makemigrations and looking at showmigrations, it looks like all have been made. Is there something that I am missing? or do I need to go into my DB and create the table manually?

Comment: Show some code or any kind of thing from which we can clearly understand your problem . Show the error atleast .

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am very late to this, but I just had the problem and solved it. So here is how I solved the issue:

In my case this problem happened because I first added 'allauth.socialaccount' (including "makemigrations" and "migrate" to this app), and later added 'django.contrib.sites'(including "makemigrations" and "migrate" to this app as well). Performing 'makemigrations' and 'migrate' to 'django.contrib.sites' was also troubling, but I will skip this problem because it is not directly related to this question.

Due to this the 'socialaccount_socialapp_sites' was not added, so I did the following:

1. In settings.py file comment out 'django.contrib.sites'.
2. In the terminal, run "python manage.py migrate socialaccount zero" (this has some risks such as losing data related to socialaccount, but I had no data because I was in the development phase).
3. In settings.py file remove the hashtag for 'django.contrib.sites'.
4. In the terminal, run "python manage.py makemigrations socialaccount" and "python manage.py migrate socialaccount"

This created the 'socialaccount_socialapp_sites' table in my database :)

I hope this helps anyone else in the future!